# Regular Expression for a max of 3 letters (both cases) followed by any # of digits

Tags: c#, regex

I need some help with regular expression as I'm learning it more. Basically I want to be able to find cases where there is a max of 3 letters (both cases) followed by any # of digits.

```
Here are some scenarios:

AB1234 (OK)
ABC123 (OK)
AB12D3 (Error)
123AB (Error)
```

Thank you!

Comment: `^[A-Za-z]{1,3}\d+$` perhaps?

Comment: @Nick you're right - I linked the incorrect one by accident.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

`[A-Za-z]{1,3}[0-9]+`